# Regular Expression for string in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a regular expression for these find of strings

```
05 IMA-POLICY-ID         PIC X(15).               00020068

05 (AMENT)-GROUPCD       PIC X(10).
```

I want to parse anything between 05 and first tab .
The line might start with tabs or spaces and then digit
Initial number can be anything 05,10,15 .

So In the first line I need to pasrse `IMA-POLICY-ID` and in second line `(AMENT)-GROUPCD`

This is the code i have written and its not finding the pattern where am i going wrong ?

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+\\s\\S+\t$"); 
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(line); 
System.out.println("m1 =="+m1.group());
```

Comment: And remove the anchor.

Comment: @devnull: `\t` should also work (it matches the literal tab character instead of the tab metacharacter, but that works identically).

Comment: Hi , the line might start with tabs or spaces and then digit

Answer (score 3):

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:05|1[05])\\b[^\\t]*\\t");
```

will match anything from `05`, `10` or `15` until the nearest `\t`.

**Explanation:**

```
\b           # Start of number/word
(?:05|1[05]) # Match 05, 10 or 15
\b           # End of number/word
[^\t]*       # Match any number of characters except tab
\t           # Match a tab
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern expects the line to end after `IMA-POLICY-ID` etc, because of the `$` at the end.

If there is no white space in the string you want to match (I assume there isn't because of your use of `\S+`, I'd change the pattern to `^\d+\s+(\S+)` which should be sufficient to match any number at the start of a line, followed by whitespace and then the group of non-whitespace characters you want to match (note that a tab is whitespace as well).

If you need to match until the first tab or the end of the input and include other whitespace, replace `(\S+)` with `([^\t]+)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d+\s+([^\s]+)
```

this will match your requirement

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/rQ7fT3

Answer (score 2):

I can see two things that might prevent your `Pattern` from working.

1. Firstly your input `Strings` contain multiple tab-separated values, therefore the `$` "end-of-input" character at the end of your `Pattern` will fail to match the `String`
2. Secondly, you want to find what's in between `05` (etc.) and the 1st tab. Therefore you need to wrap your desired expression between parenthesis (e.g. `(\\S+)`) and refer it by its group number (in this case, it would be group `1`)

Here's an example:

```
String input = "05 IMA-POLICY-ID\tPIC X(15).\t00020068" +
                "\r\n05 (AMENT)-GROUPCD\tPIC X(10).";
//                           | 0, 1, or 5 twice (refine here if needed)
//                           |       | 1 whitespace
//                           |       |  | your queried expression (here I use a 
//                           |       |  | reluctant dot search
//                           |       |  |    | tab
//                           |       |  |    |  | anything after, reluctant
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[015]{2}\\s(.+?)\t.+?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: IMA-POLICY-ID
Found: (AMENT)-GROUPCD
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is almost correct. Just remove the `\t$` at the end of your regex. and capture the `\\S+` as a group.

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+\\s(\\S+)");
```

Now print it as:

```
if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i came up with and it worked :

```
String re = "^\\s+\\d+\\s+([^\\s]+)";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(re, Pattern.MULTILINE); 
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(line);
```